# MVC5 Exception on ActionFilterAttribute captured by a custom HandleErrorAttribute changes the StackTrace

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a ActionFilterAttribute like that

```
public class DataModelAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{   
    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        ...
        throw filterContext.Exception;  //StackTrace is fine (pointing to my controller)
    }
}
```

I have a global error filter like that:

```
public class OncHandleErrorAttribute : HandleErrorAttribute
{
    public override void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
    {
        var ex = context.Exception; //Here StackTrace points to DataModelAttribute file
    }
}
```

So I lost my original StackTrace ... How can I preserve that ?

Comment: I solved this issue using this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17806299/custom-errorhandling-action-filter-that-catches-only-certain-type-of-exceptions. Hope its helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you cant just use `throw` instead of `throw filterContext.Exception` as suggested by [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182363.aspx).

So you should throw a new Exception and include the original exception as inner exception as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14653920/how-can-i-preserve-the-stack-trace-when-exception-is-thrown-on-non-ui-thread).

Answer (score 0):

In your case it'd look something like this:

```
 public class HandleExceptionErrors : ActionFilterAttribute, IExceptionFilter
{

    private Type _exceptionType;
    public HandleExceptionErrors(Type exceptionType)
    {
        _exceptionType = exceptionType;
    }
    public void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.Exception.GetType() != _exceptionType) return;


        filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
        var data= filterContext.Exception +" , "+ filterContext.Exception.InnerException+" , "+filterContext.Exception.Message +" , "+filterContext.Exception.StackTrace;

    }
}
```